# Accessing a ruby property in bash shell

Tags: ruby, bash

I am trying to install and execute a ruby gem in my bash shell and I want to look at certain properties of the result in my shell script. How do I do this?

```
#!/bin/bash -l
source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
rvm use 2.4.0
gem install graphql-schema_comparator
result="$(schema_comparator compare "$NEW_SCHEMA" "$CURRENT_LIVE_SCHEMA")"
```

Here is the ruby gem: https://github.com/xuorig/graphql-schema_comparator

I want to be able now access the result of the comparison and perform some actions based on it?

```
a="$(result?.foo)"
b="$(result.bar)"
```

Both these are failing with the error

```
result?.foo: command not found
result.bar: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because

```
result="$(schema_comparator compare "$NEW_SCHEMA" "$CURRENT_LIVE_SCHEMA")"
```

If you are running this as a shell script `result` will only be a string in your shell with whatever your method call outputs to STDOUT.  It is not a ruby object and so no ruby commands can be called on it.  All you can do with the shell variable is whatever shell will support if you access it in shell with `$result`.

Why do you even want to do this?  Why not just use ruby directly?

Comment: yeah, got to agree with @lacostenycoder, this makes much more sense if you just do this in ruby. Did you know that from a ruby script you can use the Open3 library to execute bash commands like "bundle" or "gem install" and then get the results of stdout? It's really useful.